# Are catch blocks exclusively executed?

Tags: c++, c++11

If I have multiple catch blocks, during the program execution, first, an exception is thrown, during stack unwinding, a second exception is thrown, do the catch blocks only catch the outermost exception or catch all the exceptions whose signatures match the catch blocks?

Comment: What is "on top of another exception" exactly?

Comment: @StoryTeller, i edited the question to clarify.

Comment: Nicol's answer is good. But is it just me wondering whether this might have been trivial to just test for yourself?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, i more want an answer based on the standard, doesn't want to step in the implementation dependent world.

Comment: That's fair, but you could have tried it first anyway to discover at least that _nothing_ is caught if a second exception is thrown ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If "during stack unwinding, a second exception is thrown", and that second exception goes through the same function stack frame that the first exception is unwinding (that is, the second exception leaves the destructor of an object being unwound by the first exception), `std::terminate` will be called. As such, only one exception will every reach any particular `try` block.

This is part of the reason C++11 made all destructors default to `noexcept`.

As to the question in your title, yes, `catch` blocks are exclusive; the first matching `catch` block will be executed, with the others skipped.

Comment: By "On top of anther exception", i mean "first, an exception is thrown, and during stack unwinding, a second exception is thrown". I edited the question to clarify.

Comment: @Allanqunzi - That's exactly what Nicol's answer applies to

Comment: Note that you can continue unwinding by using "throw;" in a catch block. that will then look for a catch handler starting with any that follow the currently executing catch (if any) and if there is no match on up the stack.